# Proof of boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k\sin^2(\lambda k)}{k+1}}{\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(\lambda k)}$$

Can someone please prove that this sequence is bounded?

Comment: for which $\lambda?$ and you really should show what you've tried on this one, context, your thoughts, etc. otherwise the question could be closed

Answer (score 2):

Check that  $${k\over k+1}\sin^2(\lambda k)\le\sin^2(\lambda k)\ \ \ \ \forall k\in \Bbb{N}\\\implies \sum_{k=1}^n{k\over k+1}\sin^2(\lambda k)\le\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(\lambda k)\\\implies {\sum_{k=1}^n{k\over k+1}\sin^2(\lambda k)\ \over \sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(\lambda k)}\le 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin^2\geq 0$ and $0\leq \frac{k}{k+1}\leq 1$,
$$ 0\leq \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k\sin^2(\lambda k)}{k+1}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^2(\lambda k)}\leq \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^2(\lambda k)}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^2(\lambda k)}=1.$$